# Error processing job: Project has not enabled BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When doing a query using SDK's CLI like this:

`bq query "select * from [project]:[dataset].[table]"`

Response is:

`BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job '[project-id]:[job_id]': The project [project_name] has not enabled BigQuery.`

Also when trying calling the BQ API in an application (e.g. inside an Apache Beam job), the response is the same (with error-code: 400, reason: invalid)

The BQ API is enabled in my console and the dataset is present (removing the dataset results in a different error message)

This sounds really like a dumb question – but I asked this on the Cloud Platform's  community Slack but no suggestions on this there either.

Comment: Does it work when you query directly from the BigQuery Web UI?

Comment: Are you 100% you've enabled the API in the console i.e. https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/bigquery-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=<your-project-id>&duration=PT1H

Comment: Haven't made queries through Web UI. Have made queries to the same target table through https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/bigquery/v2/bigquery.jobs.query successfully. Yes, it says API is enabled for the project.

Comment: Can you test using the Web UI?

Answer (score 11):

- First, as mentioned in early comments and answers, ensure that you have [enabled the BigQuery API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com).
- If you still get the same error message, you are most likely using the **project name** where you should be using the **project id**.

  The project id is the project name followed by a number, and you should be able to find it using the [Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).
- If you are sure you have the API enabled and the id and the name sorted correctly, try checking the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com) for any ongoing BigQuery outages.

Comment: I had this problem and your solution worked. Can you explain why I need to use the project id rather than the project name. Whats the difference?

Comment: @vivian The project id is a globally-unique identifier that lets the system internally recognize and represent to itself the unique entity that is your project; the project name is a handy human-readable "nickname" that exists for the benefit of the human user, but is otherwise useless to the computer. Google made a user interface error here by making them too similar to each other and not highlighting the differences in their usage.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

Double check that you have enabled the BigQuery API via the console.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/bigquery-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=<***your-project-id***>&duration=PT1H

Answer (score 6):

Had similar issue today. Tried to re-enable BigQuery API, and it works now. But most likely, the problem was on [Google's side](https://status.cloud.google.com/):

> July 26, 2017 Google BigQuery reporting issues

Answer (score -2):

Let's say your project name is "bq-project". So you created a dataset called "bq-dataset". There are a lot of tables "table1,table2,table3". So you need to retrieve table1 data. First, You can try this via big query web UI.

SELECT * from `bq-project.bq-dataset.table1`