# Big Query INNER JOIN

Tags: google-bigquery

I am practicing INNER JOINs using two very small tables on Big Query. I first had an error saying Project has not enabled Big Query. I revised my work and thought I fixed the problem but I now have another error and do not understand why. An explanation would be greatly appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugNP4.png)

Comment: hi, perhaps this might of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448606/error-processing-job-project-has-not-enabled-bigquery

Comment: you should use aliases instead